# How to remap a single key in Language Input

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am pretty new to Macs and these days I've been experiencing the whole frustration that comes when switching from Windows to Mac.. All my favourite shortcuts are so different or non-existent an so on..

I can live with that, there is a learning curve and I will get used to it (even though I used Karabiner to remap some shortcuts, there are plenty to learn :) )

Here comes the real question here. I am also using the Bulgarian keyboard, one of those cyrillic keyboards that have more letters than the normal keyboards can fit. On Windows though I had one letter (ч) which is under the <kbd>`</kbd>. It is in the same key on the Mac, with the sole difference it is located..next to <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> so it is super hard to reach.

Can I somehow remap the ч key to <kbd>§</kbd> ?

I tried with Karabiner, but didn't manage to do it (maybe I missed something).

Comment: Questions regarding keyboards settings are often hard to comprehend. Especially non-latin alphabets. Do you use a special (physical) keyboard with more keys or only a normal Mac keyboard with a physical Bulgarian Mac layout and the logical Bulgarian input source?

Comment: I am using the MBP's keyboard, which has only Latin alphabet written on it. I believe it is the EU version(@ sign is on the 2, it has the vertical "Return" key)

Comment: Hmm there are at least 12 different physical latin Mac keyboard layouts. What do you mean with "one letter which is under the "\`"". Is it a "`" (which is no "letter" but a dead key and has to be used with another key e.g. a ->  à) or does it look different?

Comment: When writing in English it produces the corresponding sign - ( ` ), but when typing in Bulgarian it produces ( ч ). There are few Bulgarian letters which are produced from the "symbol" keys due to insufficient "letter" keys. Here are the buttons I am talking about - on the Mac keyboard it is the one in red circle. [Mac keyboard link](https://i.imgsafe.org/9ab09f6.jpg) and on the Windows one it is the one just above the "Tab" button - [Windows keyboard](https://mpackatina.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/799px-bulgarian_phonetic_layout-svg.png)

Comment: OK I got it - testing on my German keyboard. It seems to be a "dead" key but in fact it's some kind of a modifier key which creates a 3rd level of letter keys (similar to the shift key: non-caps -> capitalized letters).

Comment: So maybe I am looking for a solution which could(possibly?) interchange the wanted key with the one actually found above the "Tab" key on the MBP's keyboard ?

Comment: Karabiner already contains a preset to map ч to §/±. Search for "bulgarian"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35577/discussion-between-phantomazi-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Bulgarian phonetic keyboard layout you can simply enable a Karabiner preset. Search for "Bulgarian" and enable "map ч to ±":

[image: karabiner]